# Next.js 14 (App router) and ASP.NET Core authentication

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, next.js13, next.js14

I have a question. I'm currently working on a large-scale project utilizing Next.js, with the back-end APIs implemented using ASP.NET Core Web API. I'm seeking advice on the optimal approach for authentication for both client and server components. My initial thought is to use JWT tokens for client component APIs and cookies for server components. Could you provide guidance on the best practices for implementing this? Your insights would be greatly appreciated.